# How to bypass SSLVerifyClient for specific IP Address

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-ssl

I'm fairly new to HTTPD so I need some insight from the pro's.

The previous admins set up HTTPD on a Linux box. It is configured to read Certs by the user accessing a specific DNS (ex: https://cxg-now-test.abc). A reverse proxy is then used to send the user to a the app server ,if their cert is valid, which resides on the same box. This works great.

In my HTTPD config, I have a section like this:

```
<VirtualHost>
...
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 3
SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars
SSLCACertificateFile <path to cert>
</VirtualHost>
```

Whenever someone accesses https://cxg-now-test.abc, their cert is read and are sent to the app. Again this works great.

What I'd like to do is bypass the SSLVerifyClient from a particular DNS or IP Address. Ex: 10.54.12.34

I know I can set SSLVerifyClient to 'optional' but that does not seem very secure to me.

I think the ultimate solution would be this:

- All Users: `SSLVerifyClient require`
- 10.54.12.34: `SSLVerifyClient optional`

BTW, we're running Apache 2.2

Is this doable?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It is possible in apache-2.4 by using `<If "-R '10.54.12.34/32'">` directive, in case someone is wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the answer is no. [SSLVerifyClient](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient) doesn't include any options for choosing its setting by environment variables, for example.

However, you can set SSLVerifyClient in a virtual host or directory context. So if you configure Apache to serve content to 10.54.12.34 from a different virtual host or directory, you can set a different value of SSLVerifyClient there. For example, using mod_rewrite in a VirtualHost:

```
SSLVerifyClient require

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.54\.12\.34$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/host-specific-dir/$1 [QSA]

<Directory /path/to/host-specific-dir>
  SSLVerifyClient optional
</Directory
```

Comment: Sounds doable Andrew, thank you. Not sure how to go about doing this though...

Comment: I added an example using mod_rewrite.